# Como disponibilizar uma função em todos os arquivos do sistema?

Tags: php

Gostaria de fazer com que minha função percorra todos os arquivos dentro do sistema. O que eles têm em comum é o `header.php`. Gostaria que a função do header estivesse disponível em todos os arquivos que entram abaixo dele.

```
header.php
----------

function urlbase(){
    $url = "meusite.com.br";
}

      Corpo com include header e footer
      ---------------------------------
      contato.php | usuarios.php | fornecedores.php | noticias.php


footer.php
```

> **Pergunta**: Como disponibilizar a função em todos os arquivos do corpo?

Comment: Não é só colocar a função dentro do `header.php` ? Já que o `header.php` vai em todas as páginas, a função vai junto. Não sei se entendi bem o que precisa.

Comment: Cria a função dentro um arquivo php e depois inclui esse mesmo arquivo dentro das outras páginas, utilizando include ou require.

Comment: @TaoPaiPai é isso mesmo mas parece que não estou conseguindo fazer :)

Comment: Mas dá algum erro ? Ou não funciona sua função ?

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado pela ajuda. Tem hora que dá uns branco muito doido :)